# I want to develop a Guidewire Integration Gateway App that handles an AppEvent message local on my laptop, is this possible?

Tags: guidewire

I want to handle a document added event in Guidewire Cloud Platform by developing an Integration Gateway app.  I have been able to create the app and handle the events, but its really time consuming to make changes, push code to BitBucket, Build the app in CI/CD, and deploy to active planet fro each change.  Can i do this development and testing all local on my dev machine?

I tried to use the record-replay feature of Guidewire AppEvents.  The files I updated is route.properties, and ran this in the cloud but no json file is written to S3 that i can use for local development as stated in the GW docs.

route.properties file:

```
gw.appevents.record-replay.mode=record
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.enabled.cc-ae-ex=true
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.s3.region=us-east-2
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.s3.bucket=cc-recorded-events
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.s3.prefix=cc-events-docs
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.s3.accessKey=<EXT AWS KEY>
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.s3.secretKey=<EXT AWS SECRET>
gw.appevents.record-replay.replay.dir.cc-docadded=./src/test/resources/replay-log-cc
```

sample Camel Route:

```
@Named
    public class SampleAppEventRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("appevents:cc?id=cc-docs-events&events=DocumentAdded")
        .routeId("cc-ae-ex")
        .process(this::processMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this question Ted! This was very thorough and detailed.

Answer (score 5):

The entry in the route.properties file below does not match the ID in the route file.  It can be confusing because there are 2 ID's.  After you make this change and run in the cloud the AppEvent json file will show in the S3 bucket as expected

change the route.properties file to:
gw.appevents.record-replay.record.enabled.**cc-docs-events**=true

gw.appevents.record-replay.replay.dir.**cc-docs-events**=./src/test/resources/replay-log-cc

to match the route ID in the from("appevents:cc?id=**cc-docs-events**&events=DocumentAdded"") url.

[ID Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTjIN.png)